# Construct a new Dictionary based on value criteria

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

I want to build a dictionary from

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
dict.Add(1, new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });
dict.Add(2, new List<string>() { "4", "5", "6" });
dict.Add(3, new List<string>() { "7", "8", "9" });
```

such that the criteria is the count of Values of List satisfies given integer *i*.

Ex:
for `i=4`
I want the result to be

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> res= new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
dict.Add(1, new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });
dict.Add(2, new List<string>() { "4"});
```

and for `i=7`
I want the result to be

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> res= new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
dict.Add(1, new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });
dict.Add(2, new List<string>() { "4", "5", "6" });
dict.Add(3, new List<string>() { "7"});
```

I tried using Take while for i=5 but it is not worthy.

```
var res = dict.Select(x => x).TakeWhile(y => dict.Values.ToList().Count < 6);
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You say you want to build a dictionary, but then you say you want to query it... which is it?

Comment: In what language are you looking for an answer in? C# or VB.Net, since you linked both tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the original dictionary and calculate the count of values on each iteration and then populate the result dictionary like:

```
int i = 4;
Dictionary<int, List<string>> res = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    int takeItems = i - res.Values.SelectMany(r => r).Count();
    if (takeItems > 0)
    {
        res.Add(item.Key, item.Value.Take(takeItems).ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    } 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/ru7k2E)

Comment: Though this resolves the problem I mentioned, but I'm looking at the ways to achieve this via linq.